# Styles are only applying to one anchor on refresh

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I'm using local storage to save values into an array and change the style of an anchor depending on the values in the array, the styles apply when I click on one of the anchors and refresh, but when I select two of the anchors and refresh the styles disappear.

```
 $(function(){
       var favorite = localStorage.getItem( 'favorite' ); 
       if (favorite  !== null){
          favorite = JSON.parse(favorite) || [];
       } 
       $('.favorites' ).each(function() {
          if($(this).attr('data-petid') == favorite){
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(../assets/img/heart-red.svg)');
            $(this).css('background-color', '#fefefe');
          }
       });
      // This function changes the color of the heart on the landing page and stores the values into local storage
      $(".favorites").click(function() {

        var favorite = localStorage.getItem( 'favorite' );
        var petid = $(this).attr('data-petid');
        var index;

        favorite = JSON.parse(favorite) || [];

        if ((index = favorite.indexOf(petid)) === -1) {
           favorite.push(petid);
           $(this).css('background-image', 'url(../assets/img/heart-red.svg)');
           $(this).css('background-color', '#fefefe');
       }else {
           $(this).css('background-image', 'url(../assets/img/heart-full.svg)');
           $(this).css('background-color', '#25aae3');
           favorite.splice(index, 1);
       }
       localStorage.setItem('favorite', JSON.stringify(favorite) );

    });

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing `data-petid` to an *array* of favorites when the page is loaded:

```
if($(this).attr('data-petid') == favorite){
```

Instead you should be doing something like this:

```
var petid = $(this).attr('data-petid');
if ( favorite.indexOf(petid) !== -1 ) {
    // set styles...
```

Of course, you'll need to make sure that favorite is an array before calling `indexOf`, but you seem to have a handle on that.

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for a little over an hour, and you got it in like a couple of seconds. Thanks for the knowledge, and help ! It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with

```
var favorite = localStorage.getItem('favorite');
if (favorite !== null) {
    favorite = JSON.parse(favorite) || [];
}
$('.favorites').each(function() {
    if ($.inArray((this).attr('data-petid'), favorite) > -1) {
        $(this).css('background-image',
                    'url(../assets/img/heart-red.svg)');
        $(this).css('background-color', '#fefefe');
    }
});
```